# Visually create a join using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: join, phpmyadmin

I recently started using SQL Server 2008 express and it has a really nice joins interface, whereby you can visually create a join.  Is this possible on PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I could find no option in phpmyadmin, but I found http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/  which seems very useful for visual database design.